# Counting the number of missing values in SPSS file (using memisc)

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the number of missing values for each missing.value of all variables in a SPSS file. I imported the file using the memisc package. Here is my actual code:

```
library(memisc)
#Takes about 70seconds
escc <- spss.system.file(file.choose(), to.lower=FALSE)
system.time({
esccMiss <- matrix(,length(escc),9)
esccMiss[,1] <- names(escc)
for (i in 1:length(escc)) {
    x <- escc[i]
    if(length(miss <- missing.values(x)) > 0) {
        ifelse(length(miss@range)>0 , vals <- miss@range[1]:(miss@range[1]+3), vals <- miss@filter)

        for (j in 1:length(vals)) {
            esccMiss[i, 2*j] <- vals[j]
            esccMiss[i,2*j+1] <- length(x[x == vals[j]])
        }
    }
}
})
```

I'm fairly new to R (explains the C structure of my code) and i realise this is really slow but i have trouble finding the way to do the samething with lapply function in the memisc package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget my other answer, this is much faster:

```
escc2 <- as.data.set(escc)
system.time(lis <- lapply(escc2,function(x) table(x[which(is.missing(x))])))
```

Should only take a few seconds now.

Explanation: The original dataset (`escc`) is of a class that simply does not work in the `*apply` family since there isn't a method written for it. However, `memisc` also includes `as.data.set`, which does work in `*apply`.

`is.missing` returns a vector of all the values that are marked as missing.

`which` finds the indices of those missings and `x[]` subsets `x` so you only have those missings.

`table` puts the values into a table.